# Sort Table Rows according to table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td class="sort">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>p</td>
        <td class="sort">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want this to be sorted like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td class="sort">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>p</td>
        <td class="sort">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I used this code:

```
function sortNum(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find('.sort').text() < 1 * $(b).find('.price').text() ? 0 : 1;
}
function sortTheTable(){
    $(function() {
        var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.price)').remove())
        elems.sort(sortNum)
        $('table#information').append($(elems));
    });
}
```

this works but, the problem is, the output is like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td class="sort">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>p</td>
        <td class="sort">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The empty one goes to top. I want the empty ones in the bottom.

Thanks

Comment: So why don't you update your `sortNum()` function to behave differently for blanks? Also, note that your `sortNum()` is wrong even ignoring behaviour for empty values, because a [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) comparison function is supposed to return a negative number for less than, a positive number for greater than, or zero for equal (but yours returns only 0 or 1). And you're using `.find('.price')` when no such class appears in your html.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/YZcQD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
return 1 * $(a).find('.sort').text() < 1 * $(b).find('.sort').text() ? 1 : 0;
```

insert

```
return 1 * $(a).find('.sort').text() < 1 * $(b).find('.price').text() ? 0 : 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E56j8/

Answer (score 2):

You have number of plugins to sort it why are you reinventing the wheel.
Here is one such plugin

[Link](http://tablesorter.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 

$("#myTable").tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sorting - we're doing it wrong](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html). A simple jQuery plugin for sorting stuff is available [here](https://gist.github.com/2818576).

---

some notes on your code:

```
// you're binding a document ready event within a function call? 
// looks the wrong way 'round, to me
function sortTheTable(){
    $(function() {
        // 1) you probably want to use .detach() over .remove()
        // 2) "tr:has(.price)" will match ALL table rows 
        // containing an element with the class .price
        // even if they're children of different <table>s!
        // 3) $('.selector') is already "an array", at least it's sortable right away.
        // there's no need for $.makeArray() here
        var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.price)').remove())
        elems.sort(sortNum)
        // "#information" is a sufficient (and more efficient) selector, 
        $('table#information').append($(elems));
    });
}
```