# how to make two table rows be constantly attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table that can sort its columns.

It is formated with multiple rows like this:

```
<tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
<tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
```

I want to be able to sort by the Data rows and have the metadata rows just follow the data rows that they have information about. However, since my sorting code can't tell the difference between the rows, I end up getting something like:

```
<tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>    
<tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
```

How do I force the MetaData and the Data rows to be "tied" together?

Comment: How do you force it? By tuning your *sorting code*.

Comment: why aren't the other posts similar not helping you?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116568/sort-table-rows-according-to-table-data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116568/sort-table-rows-according-to-table-data

Use this post and modify it accordingly. must help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first, when you have a table cell spanning two columns like that you're supposed to use the `colspan` attribute, e.g.

```
<tr><td colspan="2">MetaData</td></tr>
```

Now, in order to tie them together, I think you're going about it the wrong way. The meta data itself doesn't logically sit in a table row all of it's own, it should live in the same row as the actual data. You could do something like this with HTML5 data attributes :

```
<tr>
    <td data-meta="MetaData">Data</td>
    <td data-meta="MetaData">Data</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your rows using the `<tbody>`tag, which can appear [more then once](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) within `<table>` - maybe it's not so common to have multiple tbodies but it's actually possible.

```
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

You still have to tune your code others mentioned to sort the tbodies by their rows instead of sorting just the rows so it probably won't work out of the box, but this structure might help you then solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

do that using javascript

```
function sortNum(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find('.YOUR_DATA_TO_SORT').text() < 1 * $(b).find('.YOUR_DATA_TO_SORT').text() ? 0 : 1;
}
function sortTheTable(){
    $(function() {
        var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.YOUR_DATA_TO_SORT)').remove())
        elems.sort(sortNum)
        $('table#TABLE_ID').append($(elems));
    });
}
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E56j8/

[[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116568/sort-table-rows-according-to-table-data)]

Answer (score 0):

If you arrange your data as below, your data and it's associated meta-data will sort/move together.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>    MetaData     </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
<tr>
```

**This answer out of context is very bad practice! The only reason I have proposed it is because you haven't provided the actual `js` code that is doing the sorting**