# Sort only the current page rows in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, jqgrid

I wanted to implement the sorting function in the grid on page level. That is, If i have 100 records and 10 records are displayed in one page having 10 rows in each page. That means I have 10 pages with 10 rows in each page.

Now the problem is. If i sort the column some id in the below code it will sort the entire rows and it will show the record (99) in the current page that was not at all present previously(1).

Now how can i sort the records that is present only on that page for the below code?

Example: If i apply the sort on some id in page1 then on ascending order I should display some id containing 1 to 10 and On descending order it should contain 10 to 1. can we really achieve this?

Please help me on this problem as i am very new to jqgrid and seeking for the help on basic questions.

```
var myGrid = $("#mygrid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'AID', label: 'Some ID', key: true, width: 100, editable: false, sorttype: "int" },
                        { name: 'Name', width: 300, editable: false },
                        { name: 'Group', width: 100, editable: false },
                        { name: 'Info', width: 100, editable: false },
                        { name: 'AValue', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: 'text' }
                    ],
                    pager: '#mypager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 500],
                    viewrecords: true,
                    autowidth: true,
                    sortname: 'AID',
                    sortorder: 'desc'
                });
                myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#mypager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});

                var mydata = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                   mydata.push({AID:i,Name:"123",Group:"456",Info:"78",AValue:"8"});
                }
                myGrid.setGridParam({data: mydata}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using back end to manage paging and sorting?

I use SQL Server to do that, so always send current page, pageSize, sortField, sortOder. The following is a sample of the same:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetGroupsList]
```

(
    @PageNum INT=1,
    @PageSize INT=10,
    @OrderField VARCHAR(32)='id',
    @OrderDir VARCHAR(8)='asc',
    @name nvarchar(100) = '',
    @description nvarchar(100) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
;WITH groupList AS (
    SELECT 
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY               
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'id' AND @OrderDir='asc' THEN g.Id END ASC,              
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'id' AND @OrderDir='desc' THEN g.Id END DESC, 

                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'name' AND @OrderDir='asc' THEN g.[Name] END ASC,              
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'name' AND @OrderDir='desc' THEN g.[Name] END DESC, 

                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'description' AND @OrderDir='asc' THEN g.[Description] END ASC,              
                                        CASE WHEN @OrderField = 'description' AND @OrderDir='desc' THEN g.[Description] END DESC
                                    )
        ,g.Id GroupId
        ,g.[Name]
        ,g.[Description]
    FROM 
        [cx_Security].[Groups] g
    WHERE 
        (isnull(@name,'') = '' OR g.[Name] like '%' + @name + '%')
        AND (isnull(@description,'') = '' OR g.[Description] like '%' + @description + '%')
        AND g.IsActive = 1
)

SELECT 
    g.GroupId
    ,g.[Name]
    ,g.[Description]
    ,PS.TotalRec
FROM 
    groupList g
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(RowNum) TotalRec FROM groupList) PS ON 1=1
WHERE @PageNum = 0 OR (RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize)
```

END

Comment: I not using server side paging. Instead I am usign loadonce:true and loading entire data to the page.

Comment: What if you use a different function to sort the table, I am talking not using sort functionality of the jqgrid. Somenthing like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116568/sort-table-rows-according-to-table-data)